# PHP - find and replace a string between two variables when the length can't be determined

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to create a simple `PHP` find and replace system by looking at all of the images in the `HTML` and add a simple bit of code at the start and end of the image source. The image source has something like this:

```
<img src="img/image-file.jpg">
```

and it should become into this:

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/image-file.jpg"}}"
```

**The Find**

```
="img/image-file1.jpg"
="img/file-2.png"
="img/image3.jpg"
```

**Replace With**

```
="{{media url="wysiwyg/image-file.jpg"}}"
="{{media url="wysiwyg/file-2.png"}}"
="{{media url="wysiwyg/image3.jpg"}}"
```

The solution is most likely simple yet from all of the research that I have done. It only works with one string not a variety of unpredictable strings.

**Current Progress**

```
$oldMessage = "img/";
$deletedFormat = '{{media url="wysiwyg/';
$str = file_get_contents('Content Slots/Compilied Code.html');
$str = str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat",$str);
```

The bit I'm stuck at is find the `"` at the end of the source to add the end of the required code `"}}"`

Comment: [REGEX](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function can help you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Some introduction would be helpful.

Comment: Does my solution generate good result? Just tested it, it looks like what you wanted if I understood properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like to build regular expressions to parse `HTML`, but it seems that in this case, a regular expression will help you:

```
$reg = '/=["\']img\/([^"\']*)["\']/';
$src = ['="img/image-file1.jpg"', '="img/file-2.png"', '="img/image3.jpg"'];

foreach ($src as $s) {
    $str = preg_replace($reg, '={{media url="wysiwyg/$1"}}', $s);
    echo "$str\n";
}
```

Here you have [an example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/lRSlhW).

To make it works with your content:

```
$content = file_get_contents('Content Slots/Compilied Code.html');
$reg = '/=["\']img\/([^"\']*)["\']/';
$final = preg_replace($reg, '={{media url="wysiwyg/$1"}}', $content);
```

Here you have [an example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/BXJEtf).

Comment: Cool, that's a lot more advanced use of regex than I currently would be able to write. Gained some new insight, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion what you are doing is not the best way this can be done. I would use abstract template for this.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('Content Slots/Compilied Code.html');
preg_match_all('/=\"img\/(.*?)\"/', $content, $matches);
$finds = $matches[1];
$abstract = '="{{media url="wysiwyg/{filename}"}}"';
$concretes = [];
foreach ($finds as $find) {
    $concretes[] = str_replace("{filename}", $find, $abstract);
}
// $conretes[] will now have all matches formed properly...
```

Edit:

To return full html use this:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('Content Slots/Compilied Code.html');
preg_match_all('/=\"img\/(.*)\"/', $content, $matches);
$finds = $matches[1];
$abstract = '="{{media url="wysiwyg/{filename}"}}"';
foreach ($finds as $find) {
    $content = preg_replace('/=\"img\/(.*)\"/', str_replace("{filename}", $find, $abstract), $content, 1); 
}
echo $content;
```

Comment: I really need to learn regex, it blows my mind. I echoed the code and seemed to have worked however can't seem to figure out how to write each change back to the original file as now as when I create a simple write to file it only sends the new find and replace not full html. file_put_contents('Content Slots/Compilied Code.html', $abstract);

Comment: Nice solution. Just add a `?` to make it lazzy: `/=\"img\/(.*?)\"/`

Comment: @ElChiniNet I feel like I can shorten the edited code, but now I am unsure :D

Comment: I've tried it and it returns everything but it outputs the same filename for every image.

Comment: @MattHammond Stupid mistake, try again. Last parameter in `preg_replace` limits replaces to 1